# Postgresql. Проектирование

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, архитектура, проектирование

Нужна помощь в проектировании базы-данных для избежания дальнейших проблем в разработке.
Имеются объекты с 15 полями (+- 2 поля). Около 10 полей у всех объектов одинаковые. Но остальные поля могут сильно отличаться в зависимости от объекта. Эти отличающиеся поля также могут сильно влиять на функционал. Привести их к единому виду не представляется возможным. На данный момент есть 3 вариации этих доп. полей, в будущем будет больше. Как хранить доп. поля в базе-данных?

**Например:**

Одинаковые поля: `id`, `name`, `desctipton` и т.д.

1 вариация полей: `val1`, `val2`, `val3`

2 вариация полей: `val4`, `val5`, `val6`, `val7`

3 вариация полей: `val8`, `val9`

**PS.**  Есть вариант, создать отдельную таблицу для этих полей, но не превратится ли это все в сложную неконтролируемую махину

Comment: Всё будет зависеть от того, что будет доминировать: операции над всеми «классами» сразу или операции над отдельными «классами».  Если первое, то одна таблица; если второе, то несколько.  Есть ещё наследование, но его [не рекомендуют](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_table_inheritance).

Comment: А что предполагается делать с этими полями ? Надо ли будет в едином запросе по разным типам объектов получать все эти поля. Или объекты вытягиваются из БД по одному, по id например и в этот момент тип уже известен и следовательно известно какие поля брать. Как часто предполагается изменять состав полей. Потребуется ли искать прямо в БД по содержимому каких то из этих полей. В зависимости от ответа на эти вопросы могут быть разные способы хранения: собственно поля, одно поле JSON произвольного формата, вынесение в другую таблицу как набора полей или набора записей (EAV)

Comment: @Mike Основная задача приложения: выдать все объекты, которые сортируются на основе вычислений доп. полей. Т.е. на основе доп. полей нужно высчитать некое число. Объекты сортируются по этому числу и выдаются пользователю. Сами вычисления будут не на уровне бд

Comment: @Mike В основном от бд требуется выдать все объекты со всеми полями и типом объекта, чтобы приложение понимало как обработать тот или иной объект. Состав полей не будет часто меняться.

Comment: Если приложение будет вычислять что то для сортировки то ему каждый раз надо будет получить полностью всю таблицу. Если поля хранить в отдельных таблицах, то вам придется в каждом запросе делать left join всех этих таблиц, что плохо скажется на производительности. С другой стороны, если одновременно нужен только один тип объектов, то может быть выгодно сразу вычислить, отсортировать и получить нужный кусок данных только по таблице с доп полями а потом сделать join к ней основной таблицы

Comment: @Mike Нам нужны сразу все типы объектов. Есть ли какие-то подводные камни в использовании json поля? Также наткнулся на статью о замене eav на jsonb в postgresql. Выглядит неплохо. Думаю, это то что нужно нам

Comment: ну да, eav точно не подходит. он быстр в поиске конкретного значения, но когда надо к объекту (а тем более к множеству) вытащить все поля, это жуть. Особых подводных камней в jsonb не вижу. при желании даже проиндексировать можно будет. Если расчетное значение для сортировки всегда одно и то же (для данных значений полей), возможно стоит хранить его уже рассчитанным и возможно даже включить в какой то индекс, для быстрой сортировки

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле все зависит от того сколько данных предполагается иметь в таблицах.

1. Если данных не много порядка нескольких тысяч то не проблема держать все данные в одной таблице и работать с ней как со справочником в котором хранятся различные данные которых не много.
2. Данных много - то ваши поля которые якобы повторяются, а на деле они различные (id, name, createdOn, status .... это стандартный набор полей) то в систему намеренно добавляют излишние данные (уходят от 3 нормальной формы) во избежание лишних соединений с большими таблицами.

Вывод. С точки зрения расширяемости системы удобно когда все разделено и вы по отдельности можете добавлять необходимые поля в таблицы. Как говорится по принципу Open Closed.

Называть поля val1, val2, ... считаю плохой затей, если уж так хочется записать туда что нибудь этакое используйте не структурированные данные. А лучше уж держать в структурированной базе нормальные наименования что бы не возникало проблем в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

ПО сути задача сводится к выбору из трех вариантов:

- [Concrete table inheritance](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/concrete-table-inheritance.html)
- [Сlass table inheritance](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/class-table-inheritance.html)
- [Single table inheritance](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/single-table-inheritance.html)

Я бы предложил подготовить примеры запросов который надо будет выполнять согласно бизнес логике и сделать бенчмарки. Чисто интуитивно я бы склонялся к single table но это только догадка, так как из описания проблемы плохо понятно что мы будем делать с данными. Как писать и как читать и есть ли хоть какая то логика вокруг общих полей. Так как для полей только таких как -> `id, name, desctipton` я бы вообще не думал об общей таблице если природа этих сушностей не иерархична. Кстати постгрес имеет поддержку [наследование](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/10/tutorial-inheritance)

Одно только пердостережение не использовать json для хранения строго структурированных данных, хоть у постргресса и хорошая поддержка этого типа. Но зачастую работать со структурированными данными проще и быстрее так как различные индексы можно подвязать к отдельным колонкам.